# Why is my clipping circuit involving 1N5819 Schottky diodes in my radar receiver not working?

Tags: operational-amplifier, analog, receiver, radar, voltage-clipping

I have built the circuit shown below and been testing it on a breadboard.

Everything works except the positive half clipping circuitry.

I need it to clip after 3.3V. It currently just clips below 0V, but a signal greater than 3.3V can still be seen. If I use 3.3V from a power bench instead of the inverting opamp circuit I used, which gets 3.3V from a 12V supply, then it works fine. So something is wrong with my inverting opamp circuitry, and I assume it has to do with not enough current to switch the diode on. How would I go about fixing this?

[image: Basic receiver circuitry]

Comment: I would use an actual voltage regulator, not an op-amp, to generate your 3.3V rail.    Also, don't see a capacitor on the 3.3V rail to ground.   Is there one somewhere???

Comment: @KyleB most voltage regulators don’t sink current very well. The short-circuit current of the LT1214 is in the 50m A range.  Adding a cap of more than perhaps 100pF to the 3.3V will likely make U4 oscillate.

Comment: @SpehroPefhany      Right, that's why I don't think he should use an opamp as a regulator.   I don't see this as sinking current so much as "absorbing a fast spike".   That's why a voltage regulator and a BIGGER cap is what I'd go with.  Like 100uF or 220 maybe paralleled with 10uF ceramic.    All the current that needs to be 'sunk' is AC and comes through that 100nF cap, so it can't be much.    100uF >> 100nF  Should easily be able to deal with the spikes.     A proper regulator IC costs what...  $0.25???   No brainer IMO

Comment: SHould also mention to OP that this won't 'clip at 3.3V'.   It will clip at 3.3V PLUS the diode drop (around another 0.3V).   So this would clip at 3.6V.   If he looks closely at the other side, he'll probably find it clips at -0.3V, not 0V

Comment: @KyleB he’d need a -3.3V regulator hung off of Vss or one of the few that can sink current. Or a regular 3.3V regulator with a 80mA or something dummy load burning up the better part of a watt.

Comment: @KyleB yes, I figure OP is fiddling the 10K pot to get ~3V

Comment: @SpehroPefhany   >>>  he’d need a -3.3V regulator hung off of Vss or one of the few that can sink current. Or a regular 3.3V regulator with a 80mA or something dummy load burning up the better part of a watt.      Why do you say that?   Not saying you're wrong - I'm curious why you think I am.   A modern regulator can maintain an output voltage with "no" current flowing, so what advantage does a dummy 1/2W load give you to help maintain a stable voltage here???

Comment: @KyleB it has to sink 50mA plus, which is much worse than no-load. This is a commonly seen issue with connecting diodes to supply rails as clamps, so I’m emphasizing it, no intention to pick on you. For example, the clamp may work in normal operation when other chips are drawing sufficient current, and fail when the processor is in sleep mode. That one cost a client company a great deal of money and reputation.

Comment: @SpehroPefhany Where do you get the 50mA from ???     I know you're not picking on me   ;)   I can see where what you describe would be an issue if this weren't AC coupled.   Are you thinking the LOAD might start sourcing current???

Comment: @KyleB the current path is from the positive supply, through the output transistor in the LT1214, through C9, through the diode, then to the “3.3V” rail. So that rail needs to essentially carry the short-circuit current of the LT1214 to ground or to the negative rail unless we add some resistance in the path.

Comment: @SpehroPefhany  That's where I'm confused.  How does this 50mA get through C9?  It'd have to be AC (unless the cap shorted...)   If there were no cap, absolutely I see the DC path.  But AC?    Maybe I don't understand the operation of radar receivers...    I can see BLIPS of 50mA (like very short pulses) but it won't be 50mA continuous.  The  average current should be something much much less.   Which is where the 100uF capacitor comes in....

Comment: @KyleB Sure, but it has to clamp those blips, and if there are many blips they add up (compared to the current being drained). 100uF means it will increase by the better part of 1V/ms, which may accumulate.

Comment: Ian, can you place a resistor in series with C9? When you clip, the current is limited by the output current limiting of the opamp which is around 50mA in simulation. A 500 ohm series resistor will be friendlier for the opamps but will raise the output impedance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your clipping depends on U4 being able to sink enough current to overcome what U2 can source. So, one output is fighting another.

You can add some resistance before the clamp to limit the current to a few mA, maybe 5-10mA maximum. That would also prevent U4 from going into current-limiting on the negative side. Forcing the output into current limiting causes a lot of heating, possible to the point of damage without a heat sink, according to the LT1214 datasheet.

Comment: Thank you very much! Worked like a charm today.